# SVN ubuntu see file diffs history

Tags: svn, ubuntu, diff, history

What is the best ubuntu svn client?
I need to search for a revision where a certain file had a certain change, so I need to view all the changes of this file.
I've found a bash script for this purpose, but it would be more convenient to use a nice GUI. Can RabbitVCS do that or is there any other nice svn gui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like TortoiseSVN for Windows, but I have not found any good program like it for Linux. I tried [RapidSVN](http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/) from Tigris too, but it is not enough for me. I think that [KDEsvn](http://kdesvn.alwins-world.de/) is better, but it could be a subjective decision. Try it and compare!